# Redireccion url en htacces con tilde

Tags: .htaccess

Quiero redirigir una url con tilde a otra con el mismo nombre, pero sin la tilde.

No tengo mucha idea, pero he intentado hacer esto:

> RewriteRule ^([^ó]*)ó(.*)$ $1o$2

Tambien he probado:

> RewriteRule ^([^'ó'])'ó'(.)$ $1o$2

Comment: Publica el código con el que has avanzado o algo que muestre la estructura de lo que intentas hacer

Comment: @Levi Arista Ok, editado.

Comment: @JackNavaRow si.

Comment: intentastes cambiarlo a formato unicode como por ejemplo `RewriteRule ^([^'%C3%B3'])'%C3%B3'(.)$ $1o$2`

Comment: @JackNavaRow he probado RewriteRule ^([^'%C3%B3'])'%C3%B3'(.)$ $1o$2  pero sigue sin funcionar. Gracias por la ayuda!